# Given a set $ A \subset \mathbb{R} $ there exists a set $ G $ of type $ G_{\delta} $ such that $ A \subset G $ and $ \mu^*(G) = \mu^*(A) $.

Tags: measure-theory

Given a set $ A \subset \mathbb{R} $ and $ \epsilon > 0 $ there exists an open $ O $ such that $ A \subset O $ and $ \mu^*(O) \leq \mu^*(A) + \epsilon $. Furthermore, there exists a set $ G $ of type $ G_{\delta} $ such that $ A \subset G $ and $ \mu^*(G) = \mu^*(A) $.

**Note:** *$ \mu^*(A) $ denotes the outer measure of $ A $  and $l(I)$ denotes the length of $I$.*

My attempt:

For the first part.
Let $ \epsilon> 0 $. By the definition of infimum there are open $ I_n $ such that $ A \subset \bigcup{I_n} $ and $ \sum{l(I_n)} \leq \mu^*(A) + \epsilon $. Let's define $ O = \bigcup{I_n} $, $ O $ is open, $ A \subset O $. Then $ \mu^*(O) \leq \mu^*(\bigcup{I_n}) \leq \sum{\mu^*(I_n)} = \sum{l(I_n)} \leq \mu^*(A) + \epsilon $.

Now, I need to prove that there exists a set $ G $ of type $ G_{\delta} $ such that $ A \subset G $ and $ \mu^*(G) = \mu^*(A) $.
I think the first step is to construct a $ G $ element of type $ G_\delta $ such that $ A \subset G $ and $ \mu^*(G) = \mu^*(A) $, but I'm not sure how to do that.
I need some help for this part please.

Comment: Existence of the family of intevals $\{I_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with properties you stated is key here, your argument does not explain why such a family exists. It is not by the definition of infinity.

Comment: @pem   It really is by the definition of infumum. I have corrected this argument. Now, I need to prove the other part of the proposition, that is, I need to prove that there exists a set $ G $ of type $ G_{\delta} $ such that $ A \subset G $ and $ \mu^*(G) = \mu^*(A) $.

Comment: Infimum, yes, it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mu^*(A) = \infty$, just take $G=\Bbb{R}$. Otherwise, for each $n\in \Bbb{N}$, choose an open set $U_n$ containing $A$ such that $\mu^*(U_n) \leq \mu^*(A) + \frac{1}{n}$, and put $G:= \bigcap_{n\in\Bbb{N}}U_n$. Then, $G$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set containing $A$ (which automatically implies $\mu^*(A)\leq \mu^*(G)$). For the reverse inequality, note that for each $n\in\Bbb{N}$,
\begin{align}
\mu^*(G) \leq \mu^*(U_n) \leq \mu^*(A) + \frac{1}{n}.
\end{align}
Hence, $\mu^*(G)\leq \mu^*(A)$ as well; this completes the proof.